# Average mileage problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to determine average cost of fuel over a period of time. I have $x$ gallons at $\$3.50$/gallon, $y$ gallons at $\$1.78$/gallon and $z$ gallons at $\$2.78$/gallon. This is just an exmaple. I need an equation so that I can do this calculation every month. Let's say $x$ is $9000$ gallons, $y$ is $4000$ gallons and $z$ is $100$ gallons. How would I calculate the average cost of fuel over those three different dollar amounts and three different volume amounts?

Answer (score 1):

The mean cost of a gallon, $c$, is the total amount of dollars spent divided by the total amount of gallons:
$$
c=
{
x\times 3.50 + y\times 1.78 + z \times 2.78
\over
x + y + z
}.
$$
In the specific example,
$$
c=
{
9000 \times 3.50 + 4000\times 1.78 + 100 \times 2.78
\over
9000 + 4000 + 100
} = $2.97/{\rm gallon}.
$$

Comment: In other words: It's your total amount of dollars spent divided by the total amount of gallons.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - thank you I have incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weighted mean.

The formula is

$$\text{Average price}=\frac{\text{price 1}\times\text{amount 1}+\text{price 2}\times\text{amount 2}+\text{price 3}\times\text{amount 3}+\cdots}{\text{amount 1}+\text{amount 2}+\text{amount 3}+\cdots}$$